# Is there such a thing as a pressure pixel?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

This is a picture of an hydrodynamic bearing. As you see, the oil pressure lifts the shaft. The shaft is realy heavy, per example 300 tons of weight is the average of a big containership engine. You can imagine  above all this the tremendous load of the combustion pressure: per example, a pressure peak of 120 bars per square centimeter at a piston surface with 1 meter diameter.

That means that the oil pressure at the lower part of the bearing should be really high.

What I can't explain is how this pressure is build up? The bearing at the plane of your computer screen is open. The inlet pressure is only 2 bar. How the oil enters in the first place?

It seems that there is pixel of huge pressure among low pressures inside a continuous flow. How this difference is sustained?

If it helps, the maths behind this is the Reynolds equations derived from the Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: What are you defining a "pixel" to be? I'm only familiar with the term used in computer graphics -- a discrete element used to compose a picture. But to address your question, the book *Viscous Flows* by White has a derivation of the hydrodynamic lubrication problem that details exactly how this works. I don't have my copy though.

Comment: @tpg2114 I found this book, it is free on internet and i will read it, thank you. For me it is a mystery how 2 bars of oil enter a place of hundreds of bars. There is a discrete element of much higher pressure next to other elements. It seems to me, at least

Comment: I'm not sure the terminology you are using. It's a continuum, so there is no discrete elements of anything -- it's all a smooth function (which may be rapidly varying, but still smooth). And pressure forces gradients are balanced by viscous force gradients (and convection and acceleration) and so large pressure gradients don't tell the whole story.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of pressure flow and drag flow?

Comment: I think it's worth saying that lubrication turns out to be *really* complicated.  It's one of those areas that you approach as a physicist thinking 'oh, this is just engineering, engineers are like physicists but not as clever, it must be easy' and then after about a year you realise that it's this huge complex thing and engineers are like physicists but clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At small distances, a film of oil is like pine sap (rosin).   It's sticky.

A large force is required to pull oil from the large gap over the shaft where
there is no particular load supported, and pump it under the shaft (where
the load is, as you say, quite high).   That force comes into being when
the velocity shear (the velocity gradient, dV/dr), of the rotating
shaft next to the stationary journal bearing, acts on the oil.

A film of oil is literally glued to the shaft, and it pulls at the adjacent
fluid, and that pull scales with velocity of the shaft surface divided
by the gap spacing.   So, when the shaft is still, and settles to the
bottom, the gap gets small, possibly to zero.  No lubrication when
starting, but recall that the oil-pulling forces are now proportional to relative velocity
divided by near-zero distance.  With increasing speed, the shaft
lifts itself by pulling more at oil in the narrowest part of the gap.

The compressed oil will, as suggested, leak in the Z direction if the
journal bearing is open at the end, BUT the leak axial velocity cannot
build up because that leaking oil is pushing out against viscous
adhesion, against a force that scales as the Z component (axial direction)
of the oil velocity divided by half of the gap distance.   There's
drag against both the shaft AND the journal holding the oil from
leaking in that direction.

The small-distance forces are the reason for much careful machining (and
for the success of bearings made by pouring molten metal against
the shaft parts).   The oil itself is the pump mechanism, and it
only has the capability to work as a pump vane and shaft seal when in a narrow
space, and while continuously drawn into that space (because it
does leak out).   Oils have long-chain molecules, and entanglement
of those molecules keeps an 'oil film' intact against the strain.

The closest thing to a 'pressure pixel' is in oils that contain particles, like
graphite flakes, to discourage metal/metal contact during the startup phase before a hydrodynamic film is established.